# Dotnet Antiforgery dll is missing in docker container in OSX

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, containers

I have this idea of having a docker container mount a folder where there is an already compiled Aspnet core 1.1 application.

When I do that a file is missing. What is the best way to make it... not missing?

**How to recreate problem:**

In my OSX host I create a folder `/myrootedpath/TheApp` and

```
dotnet new -t web
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

to create and start my hello world web app.
(I can `curl localhost` so I know it works in the host.)
I stop the server with ctrl-c.

I then create a container which mounts the folder mentioned, compiles and starts the web server through

```
docker run -p 80:80 -ti \
    -v /myrootedpath/TheApp:/theapp microsoft/dotnet \
    /bin/bash -c 'cd /theapp; dotnet run'
```

but it stops with a

*Project theapp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.*

*Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found — package: ‘Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery’, version: ‘1.0.1’, path: ‘lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll’*

I see `Antiforgery.dll` is missing.
I guess I can find it and copy it and create a new image.
Is that a recommended solution?

*UPDATE*

As I start a bounty I want to clarify that the question boils down to what is is needed to execute dotnet core code compiled outside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run `dotnet restore` (on my Win machine) I see that packages are downloaded/copied not to project folder, but to `<userhome>/.nuget/packages/`.

So, your docker image still have no packages you downloaded to your host via `dotnet restore` (because `dotnet run` only compiles app itself, without copying dependencies).

You should:

1. use `dotnet publish` to create "ready-to-run" distrib, and run it in container;
2. or, run `dotnet restore` inside docker image at least once when you change dependencies (every time);
3. or, map packages folder from your host system into docker.

Comment: I tried the `dotnet publish` command and got a result. Though: there is no `project.json` so my `dotnet run` failed.

Comment: Yes. After `dotnet publish` you should run `dotnet myapp.dll`. And you don't need SDK for this, runtime is enough.